# iOS Testing Mock Subclass With Properties Using Kiwi

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, bdd, kiwi

I have an application, for which I use Objective Resource to create local objects to reflect remote responses.

The specific model classes have subclass an abstract-ish class to give them all a variety of additional functionality, most importantly the ability to serialize, write to disk, and load from disk, regardless regardless of what the specific properties are of that specific model object.

```
superclass.m

-(BOOL)saveToDisk{  
    ...serializes and encodes all properties to disk  
    ...return success
}


subclass.h : superclass

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* friends;
 ...etc
```

Then I would call

```
     instanceOfSubclass.name = "joe"  
     NSLog(@"save status = %d",[instanceOfSubclass saveToDisk]);
```

I am new to BDD and test driven development generally. How do I create a mock object, using kiwi, to test this functionality abstractly, since I use this framework in lots of projects.

Specifically, I want to build tests that ensure that a subclass with various types of properties can be saved loaded, deleted, and overwritten.

My understanding is that this is where stubs and mocks come in, but I can't seem to figure out how to mock properties. Do I have to create an actual class with those properties?

Answer (score 1):

Properties are methods behind the scenes, so:

I managed to do this with a combination of the `+mock` method as mentioned by `@aopsfan`, then using `-stub:andReturn:` were I guessed at the name of the methods that implemented the properties. This example worked, impersonating a [TCConnection](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/ios/TCConnection) (from the [Twilio iOS SDK](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/ios)):

```
// Instantiates a mocked object:
id fake_connection = [TCConnection mock];
// Creates a faked property accessor:
[fake_connection stub:@selector(parameters)
            andReturn:@{@"From": @"fake-caller"}];

// I could now call my TCDeviceDelegate 's
// -device:didReceiveIncomingConnection:
[myActualObject device:myActualObject.device
            didReceiveIncomingConnection:fake_connection];
// Check some results on the object:
[[myActualObject.connection should] equal:fake_connection];
```

This pattern particular example can probably be generalised to other situations. It's useful to call `-stub` (without the `andReturn:`) parameter to silence methods that can't be called in a simulated fixture.

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation for you at [this location](http://www.kiwi-lib.info/mocks_and_stubs.html).  Basically, Kiwi provides an Objective-C category on `NSObject` that you have access to when you `#import "Kiwi.h"`.  This allows all objects that inherit from `NSObject` to respond to `+mock`, `mockWithName:`, etc., which is configurable via the `KWMock` class.

Hope this helps, and sorry its a bit late :)

Comment: the docs link is broken, try github: https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/wiki/Mocks-and-Stubs